# Pyspark - add another column to a sparse vector column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, sparse-matrix

I have a PySpark dataframe with one of the columns (`features`) being a sparse vector. For example:

```
+------------------+-----+
|     features     |label|
+------------------+-----+
| (4823,[87],[0.0])|  0.0|
| (4823,[31],[2.0])|  0.0|
|(4823,[159],[0.0])|  1.0|
|  (4823,[1],[7.0])|  0.0|
|(4823,[15],[27.0])|  0.0|
+------------------+-----+
```

I would like to expand the `features` column and to add another feature to it, for example:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|     features      |label|
+-------------------+-----+
| (4824,[87],[0.0]) |  0.0|
| (4824,[31],[2.0]) |  0.0|
|(4824,[159],[0.0]) |  1.0|
|  (4824,[1],[7.0]) |  0.0|
|(4824,[4824],[7.0])|  0.0|
+-------------------+-----+
```

Is there a way to do this without unpacking the `SparseVector` to dense and then repacking it to sparse with the new column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a new column to an existing `SparseVector` can be easiest done using the [`VectorAssembler`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) transformer in the ML library. It will automatically combine columns into a vector (`DenseVector` or `SparseVector` depending on which use the least memory). Using `VectorAssembler` will **not** convert the vector into a `DenseVector` during the merging process (see the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/VectorAssembler.scala)). It can be used as follows:

```
df = ...

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["features", "new_col"],
    outputCol="features")

output = assembler.transform(df)
```

---

To simply increase the size of a `SparseVector`, without adding any new values, just create a new vector with larger size:

```
def add_empty_col_(v):
    return SparseVector(v.size + 1, v.indices, v.values)

add_empty_col = udf(add_empty_col_, VectorUDT())
df.withColumn("sparse", add_empty_col(col("features"))
```